# MacBook Pro running 10.15.6 lose .local access. I can't reach my home server until restarting it. Solutions?

Tags: network

I have a Debian server with a `.local` address and a dynamic ip served by my router.
I have a number of Macs and iOS devices at home, and I can reach the Debian server with the `.local` address without any issues in all but one of them: a Macbook Pro running Catalina 10.15.6.
This machine can connect to the server and the connection will work for some time –days maybe– then it will no longer be able to connect. When pinging the server from this machine on those occasions, there is a time-out: nothing comes back. Restarting the MacBook Pro or the router is not enough: I have to restart the server and then I can reach the machine again.

I did this change in the `System Preferences > Network > DNS` to no avail.

[image: System preferences]

Comment: .local is a special domain for use by bonjour. To get to a .local address does not use DNS if you mix DNS and bonjour you will have issues.

Comment: Ok: I eliminated the references in the image above, but the server still fails in Catalina, while working in iOS 13, 14 and OSX Mohave. Any other suggestion @mmmmmm?